# blackberry simulator "fileconn.dir.photos" location?

Tags: blackberry, filesystems, rim-4.2

I am facing a weird problem on BlackBerry JDE 4.2.0 and the 8100 simulator it comes with:

```
String path = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.photos");
```

This returns null!

This works for all J2ME phones and emulators I've worked with so far. Is there anything special that I need to do to get it work on the Blackberry simulator? Note, that I don't want the SD card images path but the phone's internal storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it was not a supported/implemented property on BlackBerry devices running 4.2.  It is fully supported and externally available in later versions of the platform, starting with 4.3.

Comment: Then is there any other way to find the phone's gallery path?